# to get the name of previous month

Tags: date, unix, ksh, hp-ux

I want to get the name of the previous month to define it as a variable in my shell script.
I tried different commands available on the internet, but doesn't seem working, like:

`TZ=CST+24 date +%b` gives me output as `Apr`and 
 `date -d "last month" '+%Y%m'` gives the output as :

`date: illegal option -- d
Usage: date [-u] [+format]
       date [-u] [mmddhhmm[[cc]yy]]
       date [-a [-]sss.fff]`

My expected output is `Mar` or `March`

Comment: What are you expecting vs what do you get?

Comment: `TZ=CST+24 date +%b` gives the output : `Apr`, i want the name of previous month ,i.e `Mar`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Question has been updated to show that the `-d` option is invalid in HP-UX's `date`.

Consider looking at [getting past dates in HP-UX with ksh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2431660/7366100) for some ideas.

---

How about:

```
$ date -d 'last month'
Fri Mar 23 14:16:13 CDT 2018

$ date -d 'last month'
Fri Mar 23 14:16:15 CDT 2018

$ date -d 'last month' '+%b'
Mar
```

Comment: I'm getting below error after running this command:`date: illegal option -- d
Usage: date [-u] [+format]
       date [-u] [mmddhhmm[[cc]yy]]
       date [-a [-]sss.fff]`

Comment: I'm on `HP-UX` OS

Comment: which shell are you using?   `date -d` is working on my solaris, linux and windows/cygwin hosts ... sorry, don't have access to a HP-UX box ...

Comment: i'm using `-ksh`

Comment: hmmm ... how'd you get your example command (including `date -d`) to work, but my proposed command generates an error ... ?  You cut-n-pasted my answer ... and it generates an error?

Comment: ummm, so your example is also generating the `-d = illegal option` message?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work with HP-UX but the following works on Mac OS 12.7.3

```
date -v-1m +"%b"
```